# how to change Ipad lidar resolution

Tags: ipad, 3d, arkit, scanning, lidar

I have a proejct about lidar scan
It is not detail scan so We have a lot of problem of object scan
Along the way. I found  a some app. Its name is 3DscannerApp

There are some function such as resolution and max depth for using lidar scan.
Coud I get these infomation about resolution and max depth when I use ARWorldTrackingConfiguration?

[image]